# Proving the "extended version" of Markov's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction

I am trying to prove the "extended version" of Markov's inequality:

> Suppose $(X, \mathcal S, \mu)$ is a measure space and $h: X \to \mathbb R$ is an $\mathcal S$-measurable function. Prove that
> \begin{align}
>     \mu\left(\left\{ x\in X: \left|h(x) \right|\ge c
>     \right\}\right) \le
>     \frac{1}{c^p} \left(\int |h|^p \; d\mu \right)
> \end{align}
> for any positive numbers $c, p$.

I have the proof for the $p=1$ case. I want to use induction to prove this for any positive number $p$. Of course, the first step in the induction process would be assuming that

\begin{align}
    \mu\left(\left\{ x\in X: \left|h(x)\right|\ge c
    \right\}\right) \le
    \frac{1}{c^p} \left(\int |h|^p \; d\mu \right)
\end{align}
is true. Then, we would need to show that
\begin{align}
    \mu\left(\left\{ x\in X: \left|h(x)\right|\ge c
    \right\}\right) \le
    \frac{1}{c^{p+1}} \left(\int |h|^{p+1} \; d\mu \right)
\end{align}

How can the last inequality be proven given the induction hypothesis? Should I even use induction here?

Comment: Why is there the subtraction of the expected value?

Comment: @Snoop Because it was a typo. :) Gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for induction (you also need any $p>0$). Because
$$\mu(|f|\geq c )=\mu(|f|^p\geq c^p )=\frac{1}{c^p}\int c^p \mathbb{I}_{\{|f|^p \geq c^p\}}\,d\mu$$
So (because $\mathbb{I}_{\{|f|^p \geq c^p\}} \leq \mathbb{I}_\Omega$)
$$\frac{1}{c^p}\int c^p \mathbb{I}_{\{|f|^p \geq c^p\}} \, d\mu \leq \frac{1}{c^p}\int |f|^pd\mu$$
Therefore
$$\mu(|f|\geq c ) \leq \frac{1}{c^p}\int |f|^pd\mu$$
$$$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have the $p=1$ case, then you can handle the other cases immediately by noting
$$\{x \in X: |h(x)| \ge c\} = \{x \in X : |h(x)|^p \ge c^p\}.$$